# Sync phonebook using php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, yii2

I am working on web-service to sync contacts using yii2 framework. where i am having whole phone-book (in json array) from mobile end and i have to check which phone numbers are there in my database.

Request params would be something like this

```
{
    "user_id": "4",
    "user_details": [{
        "first_name": "A",
        "last_name": "A"

    }, {
        "first_name": "B",
        "last_name": "B"
        ,
        "mobile_number": ["(888) 888-888", "(777) 777-777"]
    }, {
        "first_name": "C",
        "last_name": "C",
        "mobile_number": ["+918000584123", "(666) 666-6666", "(555) 555-5555", "(444) 444-4444"]
    }]
}
```

To achieve the functionality i have done following code.

```
public function actionSyncPhoneBook()
{
    $amResponse = $amResponseData = [];
    $snUserId   = $this->amData['user_id'];// Here i will get user_id
    if (!empty($this->omUser))
    {
        $userDetails                       = $this->amData['user_details'];//Here i will get array of user_details
        $amAppContacts =[];
        $amNonAppContacts = [];
        //I have loop here of user details to scan mobile number array
        foreach ($userDetails as $userKeys) 
        {
            //In case if mobile number array is not given  
            if(!empty($userKeys["mobile_number"]))
            {
                // Loop for scanning mobile numbers
                foreach ($userKeys["mobile_number"] as $key => $mobileNumber) 
                {
                    //regex for matching mobile number.
                    $phone = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9+]/', '', $mobileNumber);
                    $oModelUser = Users::find()
                        ->where(['phone' => $phone])
                        ->one();
                        //Check if conttact is exists or not using exist method
                        $checkContactExists                        = Users::find()->where(['phone' => $phone])->exists();
                        if($checkContactExists                     == 1)
                        {
                            $oModelFriends                             = Friends::find()->where(["from_user_id"=>$snUserId,"to_user_id"=>$oModelUser->id])->asArray()->one();   
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['user_id']             = !empty((string)$oModelUser->id) ? (string)$oModelUser->id  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['first_name']          = !empty($oModelUser->first_name) ? $oModelUser->first_name  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['last_name']           = !empty($oModelUser->last_name) ? $oModelUser->last_name  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['email']               = !empty($oModelUser->email) ? $oModelUser->email  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['phone']               = !empty($oModelUser->phone) ? $oModelUser->phone  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['status']              = !empty((string)$oModelUser->status) ? (string)$oModelUser->status  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['relationship_status'] = !empty($oModelUser->relationship_status) ? $oModelUser->relationship_status  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['mobile_verified']     = !empty((string)$oModelUser->mobile_verified) ? (string)$oModelUser->mobile_verified  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['email_verified']      = !empty($oModelUser->email_verified) ? $oModelUser->email_verified  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['latitude']            = !empty($oModelUser->latitude) ? $oModelUser->latitude  : "0";
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['longitude']           = !empty($oModelUser->longitude) ? $oModelUser->longitude  : "0";
                                if($oModelFriends["is_friend"] == 1)
                                {
                                        $amCheckPhoneNumber['is_friend']           = "friends";
                                }
                                    else
                                {
                                        $amCheckPhoneNumber['is_friend']           = "no_friends";
                                }

                            //User Image 
                            if(!empty($oModelUser->user_image))
                            {
                                if (filter_var($oModelUser->user_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) 
                                { 
                                    if(!empty($oModelUser->user_image))
                                    {
                                        $ssEventDetailsUserImage = $oModelUser->user_image;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $ssEventDetailsUserImage = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $ssEventDetailsUserImage =Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $ssEventDetailsUserImage = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                            }   
                            //Cover  Image 
                            if(!empty($oModelUser->cover_image))
                            {
                                if (filter_var($oModelUser->cover_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) 
                                { 

                                    if(!empty($oModelUser->cover_image))
                                    {

                                        $ssCoverImage = $oModelUser->cover_image;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $ssCoverImage = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $ssCoverImage =Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $ssCoverImage = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                            }                       
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['cover_image']     = !empty($ssCoverImage) ? $ssCoverImage  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['user_image']      = !empty($ssEventDetailsUserImage) ? $ssEventDetailsUserImage  : '';
                            $amCheckPhoneNumber['app_user'] = "1";
                            //Final Response of users those who are using application
                            $amAppContacts[]         = $amCheckPhoneNumber;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          //Users who does not use application.
                          $otherUsers['user_id']             = !empty($userKeys['id']) ? $userKeys['id']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['first_name']          = !empty($userKeys['first_name']) ? $userKeys['first_name']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['last_name']           = !empty($userKeys['last_name']) ? $userKeys['last_name']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['email']               = !empty($userKeys['email']) ? $userKeys['email']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['phone']               = !empty($mobileNumber) ? $mobileNumber : '';
                          $otherUsers['status']              = !empty($userKeys['status']) ? $userKeys['status']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['relationship_status'] = !empty($userKeys['relationship_status']) ? $userKeys['relationship_status']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['user_image']          = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                          $otherUsers['cover_image']         = Yii::$app->params['aws_cover_image_path'];
                          $otherUsers['mobile_verified']     = !empty($userKeys['mobile_verified']) ? $userKeys['mobile_verified']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['email_verified']      = !empty($userKeys['email_verified']) ? $userKeys['email_verified']  : '';
                          $otherUsers['latitude']            = !empty($userKeys["latitude"]) ? $userKeys["latitude"]  : "0";
                          $otherUsers['longitude']           = !empty($userKeys["longitude"]) ? $userKeys["longitude"]  : "0";
                          $otherUsers['is_friend']           = "";
                          $otherUsers['app_user']     = "0";
                          //Final Response of users those who are not using  app.
                          $amNonAppContacts[] = $otherUsers;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Merging the app users and non-app users together.
        $amResponseData = array_merge($amAppContacts,$amNonAppContacts);
        $amResponse     = Common:: successResponse("Sync your phonebook.",$amResponseData);                
        Common::encodeResponseJSON($amResponse);
    }
}
```

From above code i am checking if mobile number is exist in the database than it will push into app users and rests will be in non-app users.

In my database mobile numbers are stored in the format of +(countryCode)(mobileNumber)

> **Example** +918000584123

But it should also work if i don't pass +91 or any country codes.

It should work if mobile number array would be like

```
"mobile_number": ["(888) 888-888", "(777) 777-777"]
```

or it should be like

```
"mobile_number": ["+918000584123","+91 8000584123","8000584123", "(666) 666-6666", "(555) 555-5555", "(444) 444-4444"]
```

How to achieve this functionality?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have multiple countries then you need to pass something to verify whether its from DOM or from database field. Which will check country and then check phone number ..  for country code.

Comment: Yes we do have world-wide application we are getting country code and mobile number on the sign-up process and stored +(countryCode)(mobileNumber) into the users table.

Comment: Simply in input box, do not allow the user to put country code, and only allow them to input mobile numbers and add one more dropdown and fetch all country codes and allow them to select country (in dropdown value - pass country code instead of country name) .. and while you make query, combine both and search with it.

Comment: yes we are not allowing user to put a country code manually user have to select country from drop-down and write mobile number in textbox and from mobile end they are combining country code and mobile number and from backend we are storing the same.

Comment: ok .. so what is an issue then ?

Comment: and how can you determine that you will get phone numbers in same formats if i stored a number without country code than also it should work.

Comment: i guess u should store number with country code .. how can you make sure which country is the user from .. country selection must be mandatory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141697/discussion-between-shashank-shah-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont need regex like this

```
$phone = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9+]/', '', $mobileNumber);
```

Instead you can use

```
$phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $mobileNumber);
```

and change your where condition like this below. You should use LIKE condition

```
$oModelUser = Users::find()->where("phone LIKE'%".$phone."'")->one();    

$checkContactExists = Users::find()->where("phone LIKE '%".$phone."'")->exists();
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged it with `mysql`, so I am answering from that angle.

The various phone number should be in a *separate* table, together with an id of the person they belong to.  That way, there can be an arbitrary number of numbers for any person.  I suggest 1:many, not many:many, and simply let the occasional shared phone be a dup number in the new table.

The table would have a non-unique index on number, thereby making it 'trivial' in SQL to locate the person(s) with a given number (or set of numbers, using `IN`).